# Strange behaviour of the following template code

Tags: c++, templates

In the code below, when the signified code is commented out, code works as expected - `Type` matches the (first) template argument.

However, if I uncomment it, `Type` becomes `char` instead of `std::string`. This is the same with both MSVC and GCC. So it works when I have specialization of `StripTag` for a tag template with one and two arguments, but when I specialize it in exactly the same way for three arguments, I get this strange behavior.

Anyone has any ideas?

Code follows:

```
#include <typeinfo>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>

template <typename T>
struct StripTag
{typedef T Type;};

template<typename T, template<typename T> class Tag >
struct StripTag<Tag<T> >
{ typedef typename StripTag<T>::Type Type; };

template<typename T, typename X, template<typename T, typename X> class Tag >
struct StripTag<Tag<T,X> >
{ typedef typename StripTag<T>::Type Type; };

/*
//UNCOMMENT THIS AND RECOMPILE
template<typename T, typename X, typename Y, template<typename T, typename X, typename Y> class Tag >
struct StripTag<Tag<T,X,Y> >
{ typedef typename StripTag<T>::Type Type; };
*/

template <class C>
struct Test
{
typedef C Type;
};

template <typename A, typename B>
struct Blah{};

int main()
{

    printf("typeid of StripTag=\t%s\n", typeid(StripTag<std::string>::Type).name());
    printf("typeid of StripTag2=\t%s\n", typeid(StripTag<Blah<std::string, bool> >::Type).name());
    printf("typeid of Test=\t\t%s\n", typeid(Test<std::string>::Type).name());
    printf("typeid of std::string=\t%s\n", typeid(std::string).name());
}
```

Comment: Removed [tag:c] tag, as this is pure C++ code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because `std::string` is really just a typedef for

```
std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>>
```

This, as you can see, is a class template with three type parameters.

When you have a `StripTag` specialization that takes a three-parameter class template as one of its parameters, that specialization is a better match for `std::string` than the primary class template (because it is more specific).

Comment: Ohhh :) Yes, I completely forgot about that. This explains it all. Thanks a lot